# how to use celery with flask in windows?

Tags: windows, python-3.x, celery

I'm working in REST app using python3.5+flask. I need to run some background tasks. I use windows 10 and i found that there are some issues in using celery in windows. How to solve this? are there any working tutorials with code for this task??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Celery since version 4 **does not support Windows**. Fortunately there are some workarounds, see my other answer to the similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51497429/752142.