# Celery 4.x stops support for Windows

Tags: windows, celery

I'm using Django, Celery, and Rabbit MQ on my project and developing everything under Windows 10 before until everything is not working with different error messages that i tried to fix with no luck. And found out that I'm not able to upgrade my Celery from 3.x to 4.x because
Celery 4.x stops support for Windows.
http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/faq.html#does-celery-support-windows

All my development has been in Windows and cannot afford to use other platform or machine for now.
I'm not asking on how to fix the project but on how to face this issue without letting go of Celery and still running it on Windows platform. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: Look at this similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51480807/how-to-test-celery-with-django-on-a-windows-machine/.

Answer (score 2):

You can run celery under windows just fine.  Just make sure to set the `FORKED_BY_MULTIPROCESSING` environment variable to `1`